# mapping float values by order into tuple

Tags: python, ros

My input in goal location is:

```
<param name="goal_location" value="2,-1.5"/>
```

I want to get a location (x,y) input into a tuple doing:

```
goal_location = tuple(map(int, rospy.get_param('/goal_location').split(',')))
```

raises an error that says:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-1.5'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving `'-1.5'` string value that can not be converted to `int` try `float`:

```
goal_location = tuple(map(float, rospy.get_param('/goal_location').split(',')))
```

The output is:

```
(2.0, -1.5)
```

Comment: If it helped please mark my answer as a solution. Good luck!